# "No SDK Descriptor found" Error - FlashDevelop

Tags: flashdevelop

I am trying to use flashdevelop instead of Adobe Flash Builder.
I had installed FlashDevelop and when I try to open it, it gives me this error -

> No SDK descriptor found : C;...\flex-sdk-descriptor.xml

Would someone be able to help me out with how to solve this? I think I might have missed a step while installing Flashdevelop like pointing to the flex sdk or something.

Comment: Did you download the Flex SDK? I don't think FlashDevelop comes with it.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. I did download the flex sdk.. though I am not sure I downloaded the right one.. when I went to this site - http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+3 , I downloaded the open source one.. is that the right one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install flex 4 sdk from [Flex 4 SDK Download](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+4)
and then I followed instructions
1) [Install and validate Flex 4](http://flanture.blogspot.com/2010/04/running-flex-4-sdk-and-flashdevelop.html) and
2) [Configuring FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3)

Once this was done, FlashDevelop works properly